# How do I disable PvP in regions using WorldGuard?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldguard

I am running in to some problems when users kill each other in their homes. How can I configure the WorldGuard plugin to disable PvP in regions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [WorldGuard Wiki](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard/Regions/Commands#Set_flag), use `/region flag <id> pvp deny`. Before that you do of course have to set a define a region first: Use the WorldEdit tool to select a region, then `/region define <id>`.

Comment: I love you so much... =3

Comment: MAN LOVE RULES OK

Comment: Where do I get the "id" from? When I just write `/region flag pvp deny` it says "unknown flag specified: deny".

Comment: @Ligeobas Check the [Regions](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard/Regions) part of the wiki, you've got to give regions a name first

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Did your edit get lost? I can't see it in the [history](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/53470/revisions)

Comment: @Zommuter Possibly.

Comment: @Zommuter Or maybe it was rejected back when I was <2k.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Indeed (Too bad rejected edits cannot be re-reviewed): Ah, in your [suggestion log](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/28379/jeffreylin?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) it's still: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18289

Answer (score 2):

Just defining the region and set pvp deny flag is not enough, because you would prevent players from opening chests and building in such region. You need to run additional command if you want to make region which ONLY works as non pvp area and does not affect anything else

```
/region flag <region name> passthrough allow
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so here is what you do. First, make a region. You have to do `/region define [regionname]`. Then, after you have a region, you do `/region flag [regionname] pvp deny`.

To make it enabled again, you do `/region flag [regionname] pvp accept`.

Comment: You just copied Zommuter's answer... Again...

Answer (score -2):

make like this: `/region define test`
make like this id you have done: `/region flag test pvp deny`

Comment: You just copied Zommuter's answer...